# How do I fuzzy match word to a full word (and only full word) in a sentence?

Tags: python, regex, fuzzy-search

Most [commonly misspelled English words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commonly_misspelled_English_words) are within two or three typographic errors (a combination of substitutions *s*, insertions *i*, or letter deletions *d*) from their correct form. I.e. errors in the word pair `absence - absense` can be summarized as having 1 *s*, 0 *i* and 0 *d*.

One can fuzzy match to find words and their misspellings using the *to-replace-re* [regex python module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex).

The following table summarizes attempts made to fuzzy segment a word of interest from some sentence:

[image]

- Regex1 finds the best `word` match in `sentence` allowing at most 2
  errors
- Regex2 finds the best `word` match in `sentence` allowing at
  most 2 errors while trying to operate only on (I think) whole words
- Regex3 finds the best `word` match in `sentence` allowing at
  most 2 errors while operating only on (I think) whole words. I'm wrong somehow.
- Regex4 finds the best `word` match in `sentence` allowing at
  most 2 errors while (I think) looking for the end of the match to be a word boundary

How would I write a regex expression that eliminates, if possible, false positive and false negative fuzzy matches on these word-sentence pairs?

A possible solution would be to only compare words (strings of characters surrounded by white space or the beginning/end of a line) in the sentence to the word of interest (principal word). If there's a fuzzy match (e<=2) between the principal word and a word in the sentence, then return that full word (and only that word) from the sentence.

## Code

Copy the following dataframe to your clipboard:

```
            word                  sentence
0      cub cadet              cub cadet 42
1        plastex              vinyl panels
2            spt  heat and air conditioner
3     closetmaid                closetmaid
4          ryobi           batteries kyobi
5          ryobi       10' table saw ryobi
6  trafficmaster           traffic mast5er
```

Now use

```
import pandas as pd, regex
df=pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s\s+')

test=df
test['(?b)(?:WORD){e<=2}']=df.apply(lambda x: regex.findall(r'(?b)(?:'+x['word']+'){e<=2}', x['sentence']),axis=1)
test['(?b)(?:\wWORD\W){e<=2}']=df.apply(lambda x: regex.findall(r'(?b)(?:\w'+x['word']+'\W){e<=2}', x['sentence']),axis=1)
test['(?V1)(?b)(?:\w&&WORD){e<=2}']=df.apply(lambda x: regex.findall(r'(?V1)(?b)(?:\w&&'+x['word']+'){e<=2}', x['sentence']),axis=1)
test['(?V1)(?b)(?:WORD&&\W){e<=2}']=df.apply(lambda x: regex.findall(r'(?V1)(?b)(?:'+x['word']+'&&\W){e<=2}', x['sentence']),axis=1)
```

To load the table into your environment.

Comment: Are these inline modifiers `(?V1)`, `(?b)` and what do they mean?

Comment: How do you compare a _fuzzy_ word with a real word? Are you using a dictionary of some kind? The easiest way is to split on whitespace and use a custom ternary tree that you write of all the words in a dictionary. As you traverse the tree, you could allow for _N_ letters out of place. You'd need special branching code.

Comment: @sln: he is speaking about this module: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex

Comment: Yes, `(?V1)` forces regex to use version 1 (instead of 0) of its string matching behavior. `(?b)` is the BESTMATCH flag. It's partially in the linked docs. The *fuzzy* word is simply any character sequence that is within 2 errors of the *principal word* as defined above :)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte - Yeah, that's what I thought. That module has got too much to comprehend. Even I don't want to parse it's constructs.

Comment: `(?V1)` is used to enable set operators like `&&`

Comment: @zelusp - If that `regex` module can do fuzzy, one or two letters missing. Make a regex out of a dictionary (or the words you're interested in). This _[HERE](http://www.regexformat.com/version_files/Rx5_ScrnSht01.jpg)_ has got this tool  (functional in the trial version) that does just that. It creates a ternary tree out of dictionary words or strings. Here is a [175,000](http://www.regexformat.com/Dnl/_Samples/_Ternary_Tool%20(Dictionary)/___txt/_ASCII_175,000_word_Mix_A-Z_Multi_Lined.txt) word one.

Comment: @zelusp: The && in those regexes isn't a set operator, it's just a literal. Set operators occur only in character sets, between "[" and "]".

Comment: regexformat's strings to regex looks awesome! I definitely have an application for that. Here, though, something tells me a solution is a tweak to my regular expressions (as @MRAB points out - thanks!).

Comment: Do you want to write a spell checker?

Comment: The ultimate goal is to count how many times a word (perhaps misspelled) is mentioned in some arbitrary length string.

Comment: \w matches 1 word character and \W matches 1 non-word character. They aren't word-boundary checks. \b is the word-boundary check. There's also \m for the start-of-word and \M for the end-of-word boundary checks. You'll probably want to put them outside the fuzzy bit if you want to ensure that they are enforced.

Comment: @MRAB, `'(?b)\m(?:WORD){e<=2}\M'` hits the nail on the head (and no where else). If you want to answer, I'll count it. Grazie!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do `'(?b)\m(?:WORD){e<=2}\M'`